# How to save old version of Linux app when upgrading (e.g. MySQL) in case of problems?

Tags: mysql, upgrade

I have MySQL 5.1 on an Ubuntu machine and want to upgrade to 5.5. But in case anything goes wrong, it would be nice to have the old version still there somewhere.

[This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading.html) states:

> If you are cautious about using new versions, you can always rename
>   your old mysqld before installing a newer one. For example, if you are
>   using a version of MySQL 5.1 and want to upgrade to 5.5, rename your
>   current server from **mysqld** to **mysqld-5.1**. If your new mysqld then does
>   something unexpected, you can simply shut it down and restart with
>   your old mysqld.

Am I to just do this:

$ cd /user/sbin/
$ mv mysqld mysqld-5.1

or perhaps this?

$ cp mysqld mysqld-5.1

Answer (score 0):

I like to use symbolic links for *all* version able artefacts, both executables and deployables.

In the path I use .../mysql/current/bin and link the corresponding dir from the actual install through it.